# ErrorException: Undefined variable laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass variables from controller to view i tried both compact and with but nothing works, i get this error:

> ErrorException undefined variable: programs.

### Controller

```
public function getManageCourse(){
    $programs = Program::all();
    $academics = Academic::orderBy('academic_id','DESC')->get();
    return view(('courses.manageCourse'),compact('programs','academics'));
}
```

### View

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="program">Course</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="program_id" id="program_id">
            <option value="">------------</option>
            @foreach($programs as $key =>$p)
                <option value="{{$p->$program_id}}">{{$y->program}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-plus" id="add-more-program"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked into similar problems but i didn't find a solution, why is this happening? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: try dding $programs and tell us what u get

Comment: whats your result for  ```dd($programs)``` ?

Comment: How does that work? @flex_

Comment: dd($programs) gives me an array that contains information about programs: $fillable, primarykey, $timestamps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution i was doing `$p->$program_id` instead of `$p->program_id`

Answer (score 3):

make it like this:

```
return view('courses.manageCourse',compact('programs','academics'));
```

not like you are doing it:

```
return view(('courses.manageCourse'),compact('programs','academics'));
```

Comment: <option value="{{$p->$program_id}}">{{$y->program}}</option>  what is that $y change it to $p

Comment: my bad it is supposed to be $p i just copied the academics code but still not working

Comment: die dump programs and academics before passing to the view see what you get ?

Comment: I found it it is $p->program_id and not $p->$program_id. so stupid of me. Thank you for helping

Comment: Would appreciate marking this as accepted answer so everyone knows that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
return view('courses.manageCourse',compact('programs','academics'));
```

and

```
<option value="{{$p->$program_id}}">{{$p->program}}</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="{{$p->$program_id}}">{{$y->program}}</option>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure to explain your reasoning when answering a question :)